# How to disable combo box in ext js

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have grid that have Country and State column. This grid data add using combo box. After add data i want to fully disable combo box in the grid

**This my code for disable combo box**

```
gridRegionsRoweditor.on('beforeedit', function(roweditor, rowIndex){
            var  record = this.gridRegions.store.getAt(rowIndex);

            if(typeof record.data.ROWDATE != 'undefined'){
               grdcmbCountry.setDisabled(true);
               grdcmbState.setDisabled(true);
               return false;
            }else{
               grdcmbCountry.setDisabled(false);
               grdcmbState.setDisabled(false);
            }
      },this);
```

Above solution not perfect to me. when i double click on the one of the combo box that  view unclear combo box. How can avoided this unclear combo box form the grid?(when i disable combo box that want to look like label). Is that possible to remove double click event in the these cell for my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use this function and check

```
setDisabled(true/false);
```

or else check [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-processRawValue) link

Comment: yes i did (code line No. 4 and 5)"setDisabled(true)" but that is show unclear(blur) combo box as above

Comment: This question is about **ExtJS3** so referencing to **ExtJS4** is not helpful here

Answer (score 0):

for disable combo in extjs use

```js
grdcmbState.setDisabled(true);
```

above code work for me